# How to restore a page state after changing page using a fadeout CSS animation

Tags: javascript, css

I am using this script to transition between pages:

```
window.transitionToPage = function (href) {
  document.querySelector('body').style.animation = "fadeOut 1s ease-out 0s 1 normal"
  document.querySelector('body').style.animationFillMode = "backwards";
  setTimeout(() =>  window.location.href = href, 750)
}
```

And:

```
@keyframes fadeOut {
  0% { opacity: 1; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
}
```

The problem is when I use the browser history to come back to a page, the opacity is 0 and I can no longer see the page. I tried changing te animationfillmode, but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Could you pause the animation then set the opacity of body back to 1 just before  changing the window location?

Comment: I added this `document.querySelector('body').style.opacity = "1"` and `document.querySelector('body').style.animationPlayState = "paused"`, but still the same problem